# Sum of a row with different variables holding different values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif

I have a row containing multiple variables, e.g. `V`, `N` and `D` with each representing a different value, e.g. `V` is `8` for that row, `N` is `5` for that row and `D` is `-4` for that row. I want Excel to sum up all values. However, SUMIF only supports numbers.

[image: SO34240516 question example]

Is there a way in Excel?

Comment: If I got right your request you can easily use COUNTIF instead of SUMIF and then multiply the result for the value of the variable. In your picture for instance I see three V, so with COUNTIF you will get 3 and then by 8 you have 24 as result.

Comment: I am asking if theres another way of achieving this

Comment: `=SUMPRODUCT((A2:AD2="D")*-4+(A2:AD2="N")*5+(A2:AD2="V")*8)`

Comment: @pnuts He said he wanted an alternative to `SUMIF()` since it didn't work with letters. `COUNTIF()`, `SUMPRODUCT()` are both answers to his question.

Comment: @pnuts Maybe because this is the only option he has always known. But yes I agree that it needs to be reformulated to better reflect that.

Comment: edited.. thanks for answers :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the sake of the similarity with SUMIF I suggest:

```
=8*COUNTIF(A2:AD2,"V")+5*COUNTIF(A2:AD2,"N")-4*COUNTIF(A2:AD2,"D")
```

though SUMPRODUCT would be slightly shorter.

[COUNTIF](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIF-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34).

An alternative, though potentially confusing, is to enter the actual numbers into the relevant cells, so a standard SUM function would be adequate, and to apply Conditional Formatting to *display* `8` as `V` etc.